# How do I manually add a printer, auto keeps detecting wrong printer

Tags: printing

How can I MANUALLY change the model, when Ubuntu detects printer, it detects the wrong drivers.

The auto system keeps selecting Olivetti when the driver must be Kyocera FS-C5400DN.

Many thanks

Comment: it would be great for anybody else having the same problem if you can add an answer... we can alway upvote you as well!

Comment: Sorted it, I found a way around it.. install the printer when in Unity (able to select manually driver from list) , once installed, log out and back into Gnome 3. Printer then installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also run `/usr/bin/system-config-printer` without restarting Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted it, I found a way around it.. install the printer when in Unity (able to select manually driver from list) , once installed, log out and back into Gnome 3. Printer then installed.